# Sending a invite into google calendar

Tags: python, automation, google-calendar-api

I want to develop a app or a simple script which will parse through lines and create a even out of it and add a invite in google calendar? Is there some api which can speak with google calendar to add events in calendar. I will prefer to write the code in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Calendar API:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events